# Deploy a local webservice on many machines - is it the right strategy?

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, unity-game-engine

I was wondering about the best way to deliver private web service instances to lots of users, so the user would always be able to connect to their own offline version of a service, just like running a web service from visual studios while debugging. I was struggling with setting this up in VS2013 even with the many online tutorials, but I am not sure if its not working because it was never supposed to work this way.

I have provided this in-depth explanation of my issue as i am not sure i am going about this in the right way and would appreciate feedback:

**Background:**

I have a web service to interface with an engine. This deals with the front-end and builds a set of commands for how to make a CAD model. These commands are for controlling the 3rd party CAD software's API. Therefore the engine can be seen to have two main functions -

1. Build the CAD's API instructions, which can be saved for later
2. Execution, where it **catches the instance of the CAD software
       running on the same computer** and it builds the model.

The second part is restricted for the general public. Only our in-house users should be able to use it. However, they want to have an otherwise identical front-end and user experience.

The problem is, if they connect to the same engine as the public, which exists on our main server, then the engine will be looking for an instance of the CAD package on the *same machine as itself* - i.e the server, as stressed in the emboldened point above. What should happen is the engine finds the CAD  instance running on the machine that the controlling UI is based on and it uses that for its target. I have spoke to the CAD API support and they say they do not know how to do that.

And so we get to my solution of providing an offline stand alone of my web service on each of the employees computers. This means the front-end will check at the start of the session if a localhost connection is available. If not it will use the main address, which takes it to my server. Otherwise it uses the local engine which will look perform the default behavior of looking for a CAD package on the same machine as itself. Because its locally installed that is now the right machine and it will find the CAD instance of the user successfully.

**Final points:**

- The engine cannot be accessed by the UI directly as i am using
  Unity3D for the front-end and there is .Net compatibility issues.
- I need a completely self contained version of the software in the
  future anyway, so eventually i have to deal with having the engine
  accessed locally

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using IISExpress. I got the user to install this and then get them to call a batch file installer i made which sets up the config file and moves my web project to the correct directory.